# Quantity within side of add to cart in catalog area

Tags: magento2, catalog

I'm a little new to the magento 2 area and I'm not finding a way to put a quantity counter to be added to the cart next to "add to cart" in the catalog area, as in the illustrative image, I'm using a luma copy as theme, could someone give me a north.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Similar to what is already in the cart, but I need to bring it to the catalog part.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Magento 2.3.3
Theme: Luma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override the `list.phtml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

and add below code after **Add To Cart** button and inside form tag:

```
<?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?=  $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?= Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <div class="field qty">
        <div class="control quantity-box" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
            <input type="number"
                name="qty"
                id="qty-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                maxlength="12"
                value="<?php echo '1' ?>"
                title="<?php echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"
            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
            class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

[image]

I have added qty box before **Add To Cart** Button in my code. but you can add as per your requirement. and the quantity box should be inside the form tag.

Hope this will help you!